# How to solve jms activemq error?

Tags: activemq-classic, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have downloaded sample work light project from getting started tutorials that implements JMS adapter with activeMQ Messsage broker. I got the following error.

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received:   
org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory cannot be cast to 
javax.jms.ConnectionFactory. Closing the connection. [project Adapters].
```

I don't know what jars needed to add in this project.I have added activemq-all-5.3.0
only.

**JMSAdapter.xml:**

```
<displayName>JMSAdapter</displayName>
<description>JMSAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="jms:JMSConnectionPolicyType">
        <!-- uncomment this if you want to use an external JNDI  repository

        <namingConnection   url="MY_JNDI_URL"

    initialContextFactory="providers_intial_context_factory_class_name"
                            user="JNDIUserName"
                            password="JNDIPassword"/>

         -->             
        <namingConnection url="tcp:/9.148.225.170:61616"

    initialContextFactory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
                user="admin"
                password="admin"/>


        <jmsConnection
                connectionFactory="ConnectionFactory"
                user="admin"
                password="admin"
                /> 



    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="10"/>
   </connectivity>

<procedure name="writeMessage"/>
<procedure name="readMessage"/>
<procedure name="readAllMessages"/>
   </wl:adapter>
```

**JMSAdapter-impl.xml:**

```
      // The name of the JMS Administered object that you have already placed in the         
      repository of your choice
     var DESTINATION = "dynamicQueues/IBMWorklight";

     /**
     * Write a message to the destination with a user defined property.
      * @param messagebody
      *            
      * @returns the result which includes the MessageID
      */
       function writeMessage(messagebody) {

var inputData = {
        destination: "dynamicQueues/IBMWorklight",
        message:{       
            body: messagebody,
            properties:{
                MY_USER_PROPERTY:123456
            }
        }
    };

return WL.Server.writeJMSMessage(inputData);
   }

      /**
      * Read a message from the destination.
      * 
      * @returns the message
      */
    function readMessage() {
var result = WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage({
    destination: "dynamicQueues/IBMWorklight",
    timeout: 60
     });

/*var inputData = {
        destination: "dynamicQueues/IBMWorklight",
        timeout: 60
    };

return WL.Server.readSingleJMSMessage(inputData);*/
return result;

     }


      /**

       *
       * Write some messages to a queue then read all available messages from the                     
       destination. 

      * @return - the read messages.

      */



         function readAllMessages() {
  // As this is a test module write some test messages by calling the above  
     function.
writeMessage();
writeMessage();
writeMessage();

var inputData = {
        destination: DESTINATION,
        timeout: 60
    };
// Now call the JMSAdapter function to read all the messages that we just wrote
return WL.Server.readAllJMSMessages(inputData);


     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The jar files that need to be added to your project in case you are using ActiveMQ are :

1. activemq-client... (the rest of the name depends on your activeMQ version)
2. geronimo-j2ee...   (the rest of the name depends on your activeMQ version)

Comment: @Shumlik I have added..But it shows the following error [ERROR   ] FWLSE0005W: JMS connection exception received: Invalid broker URL. Closing the connection. [project Adapters]

Comment: @Shumulik Bardosh I have added those two jars.But still shows that exception

Comment: @Bernice can you try adding the '/' to your url? Right now you have tcp:/9.... Can you try tcp://9...?